# wrong value class: org.apache.mahout.math.VarLongWritable is not class org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

When I use mahout and Hadoop to do some recommendation, I met a problem.

The error massage is:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: org.apache.mahout.math.VarLongWritable is not class org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.append(SequenceFile.java:1378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat$1.write(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

And, The main function is:

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

```
    job.setMapperClass(FilesToItemPrefsMapper.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(VarLongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(VarLongWritable.class);

    job.setReducerClass(FileToUserVectorReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(VarLongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(VectorWritable.class);

    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
    SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressionType(job,CompressionType.NONE);
```

The mapper is:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        Matcher m = NUMBERS.matcher(line);
        m.find();
        VarLongWritable userID = new VarLongWritable(Long.parseLong(m.group()));
        VarLongWritable itemID = new VarLongWritable();
        while (m.find()){
            itemID.set(Long.parseLong(m.group()));
            context.write(userID, itemID);
        }
```

The reducer is:

```
public class FileToUserVectorReducer 
        extends Reducer<VarLongWritable, VarLongWritable, VarLongWritable, VectorWritable> {
    public void reducer(VarLongWritable userID, Iterable<VarLongWritable> itemPrefs, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        Vector userVector = new RandomAccessSparseVector(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 100);
        for(VarLongWritable itemPref : itemPrefs){
            userVector.set((int)itemPref.get(), 1.0f);
        }
        context.write(userID, new VectorWritable(userVector));
    }
}
```

I think the value of reducer which is VectorWritable is set in the job.setOutputValueClass(VectorWritable.class). If so, why does it give out such a error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the Reducer function. The reducer(...) should be reduce, which means:

```
public class FileToUserVectorReducer 
        extends Reducer<VarLongWritable, VarLongWritable, VarLongWritable, VectorWritable> {
    @Override
    public void reduce(VarLongWritable userID, Iterable<VarLongWritable> itemPrefs, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        Vector userVector = new RandomAccessSparseVector(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 100);
        for(VarLongWritable itemPref : itemPrefs){
            userVector.set((int)itemPref.get(), 1.0f);
        }
        context.write(userID, new VectorWritable(userVector));
    }
}
```

@Override is very helpful. If I use @Override, it would give out the error message when compiling. I thought it is unnecessary at first, but this experience demonstrates it's value.